# How to get the function refactored into the target function?

Tags: java, math, refactoring

In his "Clean Code" Uncle Bob has examples of refactoring without steps, so I'm trying to replicate them while reading.

#### Original Code:

```
public int calculateWeeklyPay(boolean overtime) {
 int tenthRate = getTenthRate();
 int tenthsWorked = getTenthsWorked();
 int straightTime = Math.min(400, tenthsWorked);
 int overTime = Math.max(0, tenthsWorked - straightTime);
 int straightPay = straightTime * tenthRate;
 double overtimeRate = overtime ? 1.5 : 1.0 * tenthRate;
 int overtimePay = (int)Math.round(overTime*overtimeRate);
 return straightPay + overtimePay;
 }
```

#### Refactored:

```
public int straightPay() {
 return getTenthsWorked() * getTenthRate();
 }
 public int overTimePay() {
 int overTimeTenths = Math.max(0, getTenthsWorked() - 400);
 int overTimePay = overTimeBonus(overTimeTenths);
 return straightPay() + overTimePay;
 }
 private int overTimeBonus(int overTimeTenths) {
 double bonus = 0.5 * getTenthRate() * overTimeTenths;
 return (int) Math.round(bonus);
 }
```

The problem is in overtimePay for me. When I'm trying to substitute the variables and functions, I'm getting this result:

```
overtimePay = round(max(0, tenthsWorked - min(400, tenthsWorked))*tenthRate);
```

in the original and in the target

```
overtimePay = round(0.5 * tenthRate * max(0, tenthsWorked - 400));
```

Why 0.5?

Also, there is probably a missed ")" in the original `overtimeRate`, but regardless, why is the new `overtimePay` like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `0.5 * tenthRate` comes from the difference between the overtime rate (`1.5 * tenthRate`) and the non-overtime rate (`1.0 * tenthRate`).

The logic behind the re-factored version is that instead of calculating a separate amount of pay for the non-overtime and overtime time, you might as well just pay the standard rate **for the full set of hours** and then add on a bonus for the overtime ones.